# Can I prevent Windows Explorer's Icon from changing?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When using (Windows) File Explorer to browse the contents of a folder, the icon changes to match the icon of the current folder.  In most folders, this icon is a little image of a manila folder, however for special folders, it is a different icon.  For example, when viewing the "Music" folder, the icon becomes a musical note.

Unfortunately the icon changes not only in the Explorer window's title bar, but also in its tab on the Taskbar.  Is there a way to disable this behavior and keep the icon for all Explorer windows the same?

Comment: I can't reproduce this completely. When I do this (in Windows 10), the icon in Explorer's title bar changes, but the icon in the Taskbar does not change.

Comment: This only seems to happen when the taskbar buttons are not grouped.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue when the taskbar icons are not grouped, and i agree with the asker that this is a serious irritant. The easiest to see example of this is when you switch to a One-Drive folder. The reason I split up the icons on the taskbar and expand them to include the title info is so I can identify the app and instance quickly. it seriously slows down workflow when the app changes its icon the way the the Explorer is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same thing happen to me and I miraculously just figured it out.

I had the windows file explorer folder icon pinned to my taskbar with grouping of windows always enabled, but when I would open a window with the pinned icon, it would show another icon that would change when I navigated to desktop or downloads.

I fixed it by trying to pin the additional icon that was showing up as the desktop or downloads icon. It immediately changed back to the windows folder icon. Then I removed my first pinned shortcut and did testing to confirm. Seems to be working.